# Add entries into JSON

Tags: python, json

I am working with an API that doesn't have all the information I need in a single call, and I need to the project code it came from into the call that I am making. Right now it appends the project data to the list, but I really need it to be part of the original call. Here is my output now:

```
[{"committer_email": "justin.m.boucher@example.com", "short_id": "981147b9", "title": "Added .gitignore", "author_email": "justin.m.boucher@example.com", "authored_date": "2017-08-29T08:31:11.000-07:00", "created_at": "2017-08-29T08:31:11.000-07:00", "author_name": "Justin Boucher", "parent_ids": [], "committed_date": "2017-08-29T08:31:11.000-07:00", "message": "Added .gitignore\n", "committer_name": "Justin Boucher", "id": "981147b905913a60796283ce10f915c53679df49"}, {"project_id": "2"}]
```

Here is the output I want to achieve:

```
[{"project_id": "2", "committer_email": "justin.m.boucher@example.com", "short_id": "981147b9", "title": "Added .gitignore", "author_email": "justin.m.boucher@example.com", "authored_date": "2017-08-29T08:31:11.000-07:00", "created_at": "2017-08-29T08:31:11.000-07:00", "author_name": "Justin Boucher", "parent_ids": [], "committed_date": "2017-08-29T08:31:11.000-07:00", "message": "Added .gitignore\n", "committer_name": "Justin Boucher", "id": "981147b905913a60796283ce10f915c53679df49"}]
```

Here is my code so far:

**get_commits.py:**

```
import gitlab
import json

gitlab = gitlab.Gitlab()

projects = gitlab.getProjectID()

for i in projects:
    api_str = '/projects/' + str(i) + '/repository/commits'
    connect = gitlab.connectAPI(apiCall=api_str)

    data = json.dumps(connect)

    # Append project id to json, since it isn't created
    # in the commits from Gitlab
    commit = json.loads(data)
    commit.append({'project_id': str(i)})

    # make it pretty again for Splunk to read
    commit = json.dumps(commit)

    print commit
```

**gitlab.py**

```
import os
import ConfigParser
import requests
import json

# Setup Splunk Environment
APPNAME = 'splunk_gitlab'
CONFIG = 'appconfig.conf'
SPLUNK_HOME = os.environ['SPLUNK_HOME']

parser = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()


class Gitlab():
    # # Load Settings
    # parser.read(SPLUNK_HOME + '/etc/apps/' + APPNAME + '/local/' + CONFIG)
    # if parser.has_section('Authentication'):
    #     pass
    # else:
    #     parser.read(SPLUNK_HOME + '/etc/apps/' + APPNAME + '/default/' + CONFIG)
    #
    # GITLAB_URL = parser.get('Authentication', 'GITLAB_URL')
    # API_KEY = parser.get('Authentication', 'API_KEY')

    # Used for testing only
    GITLAB_URL = 'http://<my_address>'
    API_KEY = '<my_key>'
    API_SERVER = GITLAB_URL + '/api/v4'



    # Place api call to retrieve data
    def connectAPI(self, apiCall='/projects'):

        headers = {
            'PRIVATE-TOKEN': self.API_KEY
        }

        final_url = self.API_SERVER + apiCall

        resp = requests.get(final_url, headers=headers)

        status_code = resp.status_code

        resp = resp.json()

        if status_code == 200:
            return resp
        else:
            raise Exception("Something went wrong requesting (%s): %s" % (
            resp['errors'][0]['errorType'], resp['errors'][0]['message']))

    def getProjectID(self):
        connect = self.connectAPI(apiCall='/projects')

        data = json.dumps(connect)
        projects = json.loads(data)
        project_list = []
        for i in projects:
            project_list.append(i['id'])

        return project_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new element to the first dictionary in the list instead of appending a new dictionary to the list, try using assignment instead of `append`.

```
commit[0]['project_id'] = str(i)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I didn't realize that could be done that way.